# "IAMRoleLambdaExecution - Syntax errors in policy" - Serverless Lambda deployment fails for one account ID but not the other

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have the following serverless.yml file:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  stackTags:
    Team: Chat
  runtime: go1.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: ap-southeast-1
  timeout: 200
  environment: ${file(env.yml)}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - ${file(models/chat.yml):cognitoStatement}
    - ${file(models/chat.yml):authStatement}
    - ${file(models/chat.yml):sesStatement}
```

The definition for `iamRoleStatements` is as below:

```
cognitoStatement:
  Effect: "Allow"
  Action:
    - "cognito-idp:ListUsers"
  Resource:
    - "${file(env.${self:provider.stage}.yml):COMPANY_COGNITO_RESOURCE_ARNS}"
    - "${file(env.${self:provider.stage}.yml):USER_COGNITO_RESOURCE_ARNS}"

authStatement:
  Effect: "Allow"
  Action:
    - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  Resource:
    - !Sub "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:${AWS::AccountId}:function:mhub-cognito-auth-api-${self:provider.stage}-cogtoken"

sesStatement:
  Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - ses:SendEmail
    - ses:SendRawEmail
  Resource: "arn:aws:ses:*:*:*"
```

I can successfully deploy the code to `staging` but deployment to `prod` fails.
Deployment to `prod` is done by someone else on a different computer.

`prod` has a different `Account ID` to `stage, but I never had an issue deploying to` prod`until`authStatement`and`sesStatement` are introduced.

The error message received is below:
[image]

I'll be happy to supply additional details if necessary. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the variable interpolation is missing for your production stage.

I'd suggest running `serverless package` and inspecting the generated cloudformation template to identify IAM Role Policy for the Lambda Execution verify it for completeness.